# grpc client c++ that runs in windows code is not connecting to the grpc server

Tags: c++, windows

The grpc server and client were build on visual studio 2017 with out any error. but the client application is giving error message when i tried to connect it with the server

```
E0924 12:32:13.475000000  5800 resolver_registry.cc:80] don't know how to resolve 'localhost:50051' or 'dns:///localhost:50051'
E0924 12:32:13.497000000  5800 resolver_registry.cc:80] don't know how to resolve 'dns:///localhost:50051' or 'dns:///dns:///localhost:50051'
E0924 12:32:13.525000000  5800 channel.cc:99] channel stack builder failed: {"created":"@1569308533.525000000","description":"resolver creation failed","file":"E:\Grpctest\grpc\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\resolving_lb_policy.cc","file_line":233}
```

```
 {
    std::string address("127.0.0.1:50051");
    MathTestClient client(
        grpc::CreateChannel(
            address,
            grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()
        )
    );
```

Comment: try to replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 on the connect line on client side

Comment: It seems like you put host:port where host is expected.

Comment: i tried replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 still i am getting the error message

Comment: Can you give a pointer to how exactly you built the grpc library? It would seem like the grpc library is missing the global initializer that registers the "dns" resolver.

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/20219 may be related

Comment: i generated the visual studio solution file through cmake and build it in visual studio 2017. for the same server the client is working fine in Linux. i am getting this error in windows